# Lower bound on functions with global maximum

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and have a global (unique) maximum at $x_0 \in[0,1]$.

I want to show that there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that for all $x \in [0,1]$:
$$ | f(x_0) - f(x) | \geq c |x_0-x| .$$

I'm a bit unsure whether this is true. My initial idea was to use the mean value theorem and somehow use: $$ \frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0 - x} = f'(y) $$
for some $y \in [0,1]$. Then, I would have to argue that $f'(y)$ is bounded away from zero I suppose, but I am not sure that this is the case. If the statement is indeed false, I would be interested in additional assumptions under which the claimed inequality holds.

Comment: If it's differentiable with continuous derivative, then of course $|f'|$ is not bounded away from zero.

Comment: Try $f(x) = x^2$ and $x_0 = 0$. The above would imply that $|f'(x_0)| \ge c > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not generally true. Consider $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2}-1)$. It holds that $f$ is differentiable and it has a (unique) global maximum at $x_0 = 1$. Now i will show that there exists a sequence $(x_n) \subset [0,1]$ such that $\frac{|f(x_0)-f(x_n)|}{|x_0-x_n|} \rightarrow 0$. It is easy to see why it is enough to show that the statement does not hold in this case (take "far enough element" in the sequence for each $0<c$). Define the sequence $x_n = 1-\frac{1}{2n}$, of course $x_n \rightarrow 1$ and $x_n \neq 0,1$  for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so $\frac{|f(x_0)-f(x_n)|}{|x_0-x_n|}$ is defined well. Now note that using Lagrange's theorem we have a sequence $c_n \in (x_n,1)$ such that $|f'(c_n)|= \frac{|1-sin(x_n+\frac{\pi}{2}-1)|}{|1-x_n|}$ whoever $|f'(c_n)|=|cos(c_n+\frac{\pi}{2}-1)|$ and because by the sandwich theorem we have that $c_n \rightarrow 1$ we get that ($|f'|$ is continuous) $|f'(c_n)| \rightarrow |f'(1)|=0$ 
From this we can deduce that $\frac{|1-sin(x_n+\frac{\pi}{2}-1)|}{|1-x_n|} \rightarrow 0$ as needed.